# Verify if a column exist in a DataTable

Tags: vb.net

I need to update an item in a DataTable only if a column exist.
I've tried to write this, but it doesn't work because the column "carta_sistemata" doesn't exist.

```
If table.Rows(0).Item("column_name") IsNot Nothing Then
    TextBox.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("column_name").ToString
End If
```

Without the "if" the code works, but if the column doesn't exist it throws an exception.

```
TextBox.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("column_name").ToString
```

Comment: where you are updating the value?

Comment: in a textbox..........

Comment: What do you want the value of TextBox.Text to be if column "carta_sistemata" doesn't exist?

Comment: @AndrewMorton i'm using same form to update or load different tables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check column exists before accessing:

```
If table.Columns.Contains("column_name") Then
    TextBox.Text = table.Rows(0).Item("column_name").ToString
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Try/Catch` block:

```
Try
    Me.TextBox1.Text = YourDataTableTable.Rows(0).Item("ColumnName").ToString
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse through the DataColumn collection on the table and look for the presence of the column you're interested in.

```
   For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
       If col.ColumnName = "carta_sistemata" Then
             'do your update
             Exit For
       End If
   Next
```